# Count number of cells "A>B" in same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Count number of cells "A>B" in same row]

I want to get total count from column "B" if "column B value > column A value" in **same row**. I can do it following the process as above image. But I am looking for better approach than this. Can we get it directly from column A & B? Any better suggestion than above will be welcome here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[A]>Table1[B]))
```